# How do I find all roles that grant access to objects under a particular schema?

Tags: oracle

I need to assign a user to any roles that grant access to tables under a particular schema. What would I query to find those roles?

Comment: I believe I got it - replying to my own question in case anyone needs the info:

select * from role_tab_privs where owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME';

Comment: Please consider [posting your solution as an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer "Can I answer my own question?"). That will make it more visible as well as let you format it better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I got it - replying to my own question in case anyone needs the info:

```
select * from role_tab_privs where owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME';
```